# Pyspark transform method that's equivalent to the Scala Dataset#transform method

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

The Spark Scala API has a `Dataset#transform` method that makes it easy to chain custom DataFrame transformations like so:

```scala
val weirdDf = df
  .transform(myFirstCustomTransformation)
  .transform(anotherCustomTransformation)
```

I don't see an equivalent `transform` method for [pyspark in the documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html).

Is there a PySpark way to chain custom transformations?

If not, how can the `pyspark.sql.DataFrame` class be monkey patched to add a `transform` method?

**Update**

The transform method was [added to PySpark](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-26449) as of [PySpark 3.0](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.0-preview/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.transform).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Implementation:

```
from pyspark.sql.dataframe import DataFrame

def transform(self, f):
    return f(self)

DataFrame.transform = transform
```

Usage:

```
spark.range(1).transform(lambda df: df.selectExpr("id * 2"))
```

Answer (score 0):

A Transformer pipeline using SQLTransformer objects (or any other Transformer) is a Spark solution which makes chaining transformations easy.  For example:

```
from pyspark.ml.feature import SQLTransformer
from pyspark.ml import Pipeline, PipelineModel

df = spark.createDataFrame([
    (0, 1.0, 3.0),
    (2, 2.0, 5.0)
], ["id", "v1", "v2"])
sqlTrans = SQLTransformer(
    statement="SELECT *, (v1 + v2) AS v3, (v1 * v2) AS v4 FROM __THIS__")

sqlSelectExpr = SQLTransformer(statement="SELECT *, (id * 2) AS v5 FROM __THIS__")

pipeline = Pipeline(stages=[sqlTrans, sqlSelectExpr])
pipelineModel = pipeline.fit(df)
pipelineModel.transform(df).show()
```

Another approach to chaining when all the transformations are simple expressions such as above, is to use a single SQLTransformer and string manipulations:

```
transforms = ['(v1 + v2) AS v3',
              '(v1 * v2) AS v4',
              '(id * 2) AS v5',
              ]
selectExpr = "SELECT *, {} FROM __THIS__".format(",".join(transforms))
sqlSelectExpr = SQLTransformer(statement=selectExpr)
sqlSelectExpr.transform(df).show()
```

Keep in mind that Spark SQL transformations can be optimized and will be faster than transforms defined as a Python User Defined Function (UDF).